# Error while executing Substring Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute this query in SSMS

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME, 1, LEN(NAME) - 4) 
 FROM sys.tables
```

I get an error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

But when I execute this query here:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME, 1, LEN(NAME) - 4) 
 FROM sys.tables 
 WHERE NAME LIKE '%_OLD'
```

I get the output. What is the reason for the failure of first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your script fails is that some of the tables has a length of fewer than 4 characters. The third parameter of SUBSTRING cannot be negative.

Here is a workaround:

```
SELECT
  REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(NAME), 1,4,'')) 
FROM
  Sys.tables
```

The script reverse the text, removes the first 4 characters and reverse the rest again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the last parameter of the `SUBSTRING` function must be a *positive value*.

You probably have some tables with names shorter than 5 characters.

Try to execute this to see the minimum length of names in your table:

```
SELECT MIN(LEN(Name)) AS MinLength
FROM Sys.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

If `length` parameter is not a valid length i.e a `negative` one. you get this error.

> length:
>   Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how
>   many characters of the expression will be returned. If length is
>   negative, an error is generated and the statement is terminated. If
>   the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters
>   in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is
>   returned

E.g:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('any string',1, -1)
```

It gives error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.

`LIKE '%_OLD'` wont give error as the `Min length` of it will be `4`, so `Min` value of `LEN(NAME)-4` would be `0 or positive.`